# How to select the Last elements attribute and change its value on html with php

Tags: php

HTML file (Demo)

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td rowspan="1"> 1 </td>
 <td rowspan="1"> 2 </td>
 <td rowspan="1"> 3 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

When I'll trigger the PHP file, it should get the last rowspan of the HTML file and change its value to 2.

Comment: If there is more than one element with ID _myId_ than this is not valid HTML page. ID should be unique.

Comment: sorry but i need the select the last attribute

Comment: what is *the last attribute*? you don't know it's name? i am not sure that DOMDocument save order of attributes

Comment: its rowspan. the php should get the last rowspan attribute and change its value.

Comment: Are you able to show us part of the document we are talking about? I am not sure about structure you are using. Your comments are little confusing.

Comment: So, we are talking about changing rowspan attribute of **last child** of element with ID _myId_ . Am I right?

Comment: what in this html has `id='myId'`?

Comment: that was code i found earlier. The html have no id the php should get it by attribute

Comment: I have improved my ques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile($file);
// find the last td by xpath and set value
$xpath = new DOMXpath($html);
$td = $xpath->query("(//td)[last()]")->item(0)->setAttribute('rowspan', 2);

echo $html->saveHTML();
```

**UPDATE**

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($html);
$tds = $xpath->query("//td[position()=last() or (position()=last()-1)]");

foreach($tds as $td)
   $td->setAttribute('rowspan', 5);
```

Comment: What should I do if I wanna select last 2 rowspan.